# PFQuery first returning 6 items then 3 in a UITableViewController

Tags: uitableview, parse-platform, swift2

He everyone,

Im pulling my hears out for a whole day for the following issue. My back-end is in Parse and i am doing a query on my table "events" in a UITableViewController. The problem is that the query returns the complete data in the ViewDidLoad but not in my tableView method. In my tableView im only getting 3 items returned. Im aware of that parse query doing a Asynchronously call but why its returning 3 items?

I would be gratefull if somebody can help me out here.

Here is my code:

```
class EventOverViewController: UITableViewController {


    var events:Array = [AnyObject]();
    var imageContainer : UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyle.None;

        self.retrieveInfoFromParse();

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

        return self.events.count
    }


    func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {
        let getEvents = PFQuery(className:"Event");

        return getEvents;
    }


    func retrieveInfoFromParse(){

        self.queryForTable().findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

                for object in objects! {

                    self.events.append(object);

                }

                //RETURNING 6 ITEMS
                print(self.events);
                self.tableView.reloadData();

            }

        }
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {

        return 230;

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {


        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("EventCell", forIndexPath:indexPath) as! EventTableViewCell

                let eventData = self.events[indexPath.row];

        //ONLY returning 3 ITEMS, WHY?
        print(eventData);


        return cell
    }


    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!

        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! RootMainViewController
        var secondEventData : Event!

        secondEventData = self.events[indexPath.row] as! Event;

        destinationVC.title = secondEventData.eventName;
        destinationVC.event = secondEventData;


    }

}
```

Comment: Why do you have `retrieveInfoFromParse`?

Comment: @Wain i wanted my function be so small enough thats for first and wanted to check if thats the problem , but you're right i could place that also in the queryForTable.

Comment: When i do a print in each section / method it will output: 

viewDidLoad is called
queryForTable is called
tableView numberOfRowsInSection is called
tableView numberOfRowsInSection is called
tableView numberOfRowsInSection is called
tableView numberOfRowsInSection is called
tableView numberOfRowsInSection is called
tableView numberOfRowsInSection is called
tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath is called
tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath is called
tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath is called

As you can see cellForRowAtIndexPath is called 3 times.. im seriously don't know what im doing wrong.

Comment: When you had `queryForTable` I thought you were using `PFTableViewController`. `print(eventData);` is very different to `print(self.events);` Have you scrolled the view?

Comment: @Wain im not using PFTableViewController, i want to know why this doesn't work. I know the method is the same because first i used PFtableviewcontroller and i was to curious so i head back to see what the problem is of this. What do you mean with "have you scrolled the view"

Comment: The table loads more cells when you scroll, and your logging looks misleading

Comment: i already went back to PFTableViewController, because of the deadline i have but i still curious why it is not working.